# WKWebView not returning the correct content size height

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios10, wkwebview

I've added a `WKWebView` as a subview in a `UITableViewCell`. In `webView:didFinish` I'm setting the webView's content height to the webView's height constraint.  I've tried these two methods:

1. height = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height
2. webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight")

however sometimes the height value returned is significantly greater (>500px) than the webView's content. I've also added `tableViewCell.webView.setNeedsLayout()` in `UITableViewDelegate.scrollViewDidScroll` to try to debug the issue.

I'm using Xcode 8, and I'm able to reproduce the issue on iOS 9 & 10.

Comment: Use `NSAttributedString` to load html inside `UILabel`.

Comment: @New16 Thanks, I'm loading html from a url.  I've found a solution of first setting webView.frame.size.height = 1 then calling  webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight")

Comment: That fixed the issue on iOS 10, the issue still persists on iOS 9

Comment: @mobileDev97 Did you manage to resolve this issue?